# Mysql query to get all values with one condition and other values with same ID

Tags: mysql

I have this tables. I need to get all PREDICTION VALUE > GAME MIN_VALUE **and** all PREDICTION values with same ID_GAME where at least one PREDICTION VALUE > GAME MIN_VALUE.

In this example:

```
GAME

ID     PLAYER     MIN_VALUE
1      John       1.2
2      Paul       1.4
3      Henry      1.6
4      Tom        2.1

PREDICTIONS

ID_GAME     HOUSE       VALUE    
1           house_a     1.5
1           house_b     1
2           house_a     1.2
2           house_b     1.4
2           house_c     1.5
3           house_a     1.5
3           house_b     1.7
3           house_c     1.8
3           house_d     1.9
4           house_b     1.6
4           house_d     1.9
```

I need to get this:

```
ID_GAME     HOUSE       PLAYER     VALUE   MIN_VALUE 
1           house_a     John       1.5     1.2
1           house_b     John       1       1.2
2           house_a     Paul       1.2     1.4
2           house_b     Paul       1.4     1.4
2           house_c     Paul       1.5     1.4
3           house_a     Paul       1.5     1.4
3           house_b     Henry      1.7     1.6
3           house_c     Henry      1.8     1.6
3           house_d     Henry      1.9     1.6
```

I've tried with this mysql query without good results:

```
SELECT *                  
FROM game m
INNER JOIN predictions p1 ON m.id = p1.id_game
INNER JOIN predictions p2 ON m.id = p2.id_game
WHERE p1.value >= m.min_value OR p2.value < m.min_value
AND p1.id_id_game = p2.id_id_game
```

Comment: I need to know how to do that SQL query

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can try by placing '*backtick*' around table name MATCH and using this query:

```
SELECT ID_MATCH, HOUSE, PLAYER,  VALUE ,  MIN_VALUE 
FROM PREDICT
LEFT JOIN  `MATCH` ON  `MATCH`.ID = PREDICT.ID_MATCH
```

MATCH is a Reserved Keyword in MySQL. For more details visit:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#idm140118802075536

Comment: @kurtko have you got what you needed?

Comment: The problem was not with 'MATCH' keyword (I don't use it in my real SQL). See updated example